# Closures in a struct member (HashMap) which capture a mutable reference to another struct member

Tags: rust, closures

How could I achieve something like this in Rust

```
struct TestStruct {
    map:HashMap<String, Box<FnMut(i32) -> ()>>,
    val:i32
}

impl TestStruct {
    fn new() -> Self {
        let mut ts = TestStruct{ map: Default::default(), val: 0 };
        ts.map.insert(String::from("add"),Box::new(|a| ts.val+=a ));
        ts.map.insert(String::from("mult"),Box::new(|a| ts.val*=a ));
        ts
    }

    fn execute(&mut self, cmd:&str,arg:i32) {
        let f =  self.map.get_mut(cmd).unwrap();
        f(arg);
    }
}
```

This obviously doesn't work since `ts` is mutably borrowed multiple times

Is the solution really this ugly?

```
impl TestStruct {
    fn new() -> Self {
        let mut map:HashMap<String, Box<Fn(i32) -> ()>> = HashMap::new();
        let val = Rc::new(RefCell::new(0));
        let v1 = val.clone();
        map.insert(String::from("add"),Box::new(move |a|
            {
                let mut mutator = v1.borrow_mut();
                *mutator+=a;
            }
        ));
        let v1 = val.clone();
        map.insert(String::from("mult"),Box::new(move |a| {
            {
                let mut mutator = v1.borrow_mut();
                *mutator*=a;
            }
        }
        ));
        TestStruct{ map, val }
    }

    fn execute(&mut self, cmd:&str,arg:i32) {
        let f =  self.map.get_mut(cmd).unwrap();
        f(arg);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve something like this with a completely different approach?

For completeness I am including the Rc version:

```
struct TestStruct {
    map:HashMap<String, Box<Fn(i32) -> ()>>,
    val:Rc<Cell<i32>>
}

impl TestStruct {
    fn new() -> Self {
        let mut map:HashMap<String, Box<Fn(i32) -> ()>> = HashMap::new();
        let val = Rc::new(Cell::new(0));
        let v1 = val.clone();
        map.insert(String::from("add"),Box::new(move |a| v1.set(v1.get()+a)));
        let v1 = val.clone();
        map.insert(String::from("mult"),Box::new(move |a| v1.set(v1.get()*a)));
        TestStruct{ map, val }
    }

    fn execute(&mut self, cmd:&str,arg:i32) {
        let f =  self.map.get_mut(cmd).unwrap();
        f(arg);
    }
}
```

Comment: It won't even work if you use a shared reference, because a value cannot contain a reference to itself; as soon as you return `ts` from `TestStruct::new`, the reference captured by the closures will become invalid. You may need to use something like `Rc<Cell>` here.

Comment: I would suggest *not* preserving a handle to `val` in your functions and instead pass it as a mutable reference when `execute` is called. [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=73fde566fe12630dd70f1fe2d61ac794) demonstration

Comment: @kmdreko I prefer your suggestion to the 'Rc<RefCell<...>>' horror

Comment: That is another option. Note that `Cell` is even more lightweight than `RefCell`, and you wouldn't even need a `RefCell` here (though neither are `Sync`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend avoiding shared mutability unless absolutely necessary. In this case you can give a mutable reference to your functions only when they are executing by passing `val` as a mutable reference parameter:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct TestStruct {
    map: HashMap<String, Box<dyn FnMut(&mut i32, i32) -> ()>>,
    val: i32
}

impl TestStruct {
    fn new() -> Self {
        let mut ts = TestStruct { map: Default::default(), val: 0 };
        ts.map.insert(String::from("add"), Box::new(|val, a| *val += a ));
        ts.map.insert(String::from("mult"), Box::new(|val, a| *val *= a ));
        ts
    }

    fn execute(&mut self, cmd: &str, arg: i32) {
        let f = self.map.get_mut(cmd).unwrap();
        f(&mut self.val, arg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Additionally since with your solution the closures don't need to capture anything, the map signature can be changed to `map: HashMap<String, fn(&mut i32, i32) -> ()>` since the closures can become simple function pointers.